# Unable to add Cortana Channel to MSFT Chat Bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, cortana

I create a custom bot and now want to integrate with the cortana channel. I have previously added Teams, Web and Direct Line and have no issues so far. When I click on the cortana channel(https://help.knowledge.store/tutorials_code_samples/bot_framework/index.html) step 6. I get an error "Something went wrong with this channel. Contact us". This has been happening for the last 1 week and i tried various browser and computers and can reproduce the issue.

are other having the same issue when trying to add this channel to their bot?

Thx
Kartik

Comment: Knowledge.store is going away.  Through https://dev.botframework.com/ you can reach documentation here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-cortana?view=azure-bot-service-3.0 - And I have a demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCgqZPbQBQk&t=390s (start at time 6:30).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/overview is the new cortana specific doc root

Comment: and you don't need to use azure portal, you can try https://dev.botframework.com/bots/channels?id=<YourBotName>&channelId=cortana and connect there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the info. Contacted MSFT support and they were able to reproduce the issue. Seems to be an issue on their side when adding a channel to a bot. Didnt provide a resolution timeframe. So will need to keep checking.

Kartik